# IIS C# Azure - Get memory working set of current w3wp only

Tags: c#, performancecounter, memory-consumption, telemetry

When retrieving info via `PerformanceCounter`, for the counter "Working Set" i must specify a instance name. My problem is that on azure, `Kudu` also runs on a process named "w3wp". How can I be sure that i'm capturing only the numbers for MY instance of w3wp?

I tried to provide, not the name, but the process ID also...

I do realize i can use the "_Total", but that won't help me because i'm trying to set a base value for memory related improvements/optimisations to come, and my app service plan hosts several other small apps...

**Edit 1**
I use application insights but it does capture that metric frequently enough... I would like to capture every second, would settle for every 5 seconds, but app insights gives me the avg for every minute (and the avg part is a guess of my part, because it could be just be sampling a single time a reporting back)

Comment: Would your app even be ble to see anything outside of the w3wp process? I imagine it's pretty isolated and locked down unless you're running on a VM?

Comment: @DavidG thats a really good question... fact is that my app is not logging something nearly expected, and of constant value that only changes when some operation is performed on Kudu...

Comment: Also, I would gues that your apps will almost certainly be running on different machines anyway.

Comment: Oh, and can't you get this information directly out of the Azure Portal?

Comment: @DavidG not in the granularity i want/need... the max i can get there is a minute by minute avg... and, the retention for "per-instance" is only 7 days so far... using application insights i have 90 days retention and the possibility to do continuous export...

Comment: Well, use app insights then. That thing is insanely useful.

Comment: @DavidG check edit 1